# What is wrong with this code ? getting 0 as an answer

Tags: java, computer-science

```
public class Sum {
public static void main(String[]args){
    int sumOfPos = 0;
    int sumOfNeg = 0;
    int sum = sumOfPos + sumOfNeg;
//should give 1 , 5 , 9
        for(int pos = 1 ; pos<= 9; pos+=4){
            int Old = pos*pos;
            sumOfPos = pos + Old;
        }
//should give -3 and -7
        for(int neg = -3 ; neg>= -7; neg-=4){
            int Old = neg*neg;
            sumOfNeg = neg + Old;
        }
// should give the sum of the sqaure of these numbers
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

I get zero what is the problem?
I can only use for loops for this one.
what are other ways of getting the result needed?

Comment: What do you think `int sum = sumOfPos + sumOfNeg;` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: should'nt it add them up?

Comment: But you are setting the value of `sum` when `sumOfPos` and `sumOfNeg` are still 0. You never update `sum` after that.

Comment: You may want to spend some time learning to use a debugger. The time spent doing so will pay itself back tremendously. It also offers great insight in program flow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int sumOfPos = 0;
        int sumOfNeg = 0;
//should give 1 , 5 , 9
    for(int pos = 1 ; pos<= 9; pos+=4){
        int Old = pos*pos;
        sumOfPos = pos + Old;
    }
//should give -3 and -7
    for(int neg = -3 ; neg>= -7; neg-=4){
        int Old = neg*neg;
        sumOfNeg = neg + Old;
    }
// should give the sum of the sqaure of these numbers
int sum = sumOfPos + sumOfNeg;
System.out.println(sum);
```

}

Comment: You tell us. If it didn't work then you shouldn't be posting this as an answer.